# Javascript drop down lists dont work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

http://www.poopoostocks.com/premium-service/

The tables on this site work fine in all browsers, but some people in IE9 have an issue where when they try to select an option on the menu IE loses focus. The computers in my house with IE 9 do not have this problem but other people have showed me that they do. Any ideas?

Comment: seems to work fine on my IE9...

are they in "compatibility view" mode?

try using IE=9 or IE=edge in your metadata tag

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: Please narrow the problem down and only provide the absolute necessary code (best thing is to post a small sample that illustrates the problem). I'm not planning on going through all your code to find out where the problem might be, too much clutter.

Comment: @hagensoft I can reproduce the problem with my IE9 in IE9 standards mode.

Comment: Well this is hard for me because it works fine on every computer in my house. What did you do to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with inline css code on the page. Founded on line 121.
There is padding:5px for select element.
Better way is to wrap your form element with div (or something else) and style that div with your code:

```
background:#333;
color:#fff;
padding:5px;
border: solid thin #555;
border-radius:6px;
```

P.S. And clean up your html code. It is really dirty right now. I found strange things like `</br>` and constructions like `<p></center></p>` and `<p></noscript></p>` and that is not all strange things in code :)
Love your code and browsers will love you :)
Good luck in your projects.